# Calling PowerShell from VBScript - Missing Double Quote

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I have a VBScript that calls `powershell.exe` using the `Shell` object's `Exec` method.

For the purpose of the question, I have extracted the troublesome bit of code from my script and simplified it.

The expected outcome of the script below is that PowerShell's `Write-Host` cmdlet will print the following:

```
Please save the file to "C:\test"
```

But the actual result is this:

```
Please save the file to C:\test"
```

The initial double quote surrounding the file path is missing.

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim strPsCommand, ps, objShell, objExec
Dim strStdOut, strStdErr
Dim strStringToPrint

strStringToPrint = "$text = @'" & vbCrLf & "Please save the file to ""C:\test\""" & vbCrLf & "'@"

strPsCommand = strStringToPrint & "; Write-Host $text"
ps = "powershell.exe -Command " & strPsCommand

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objExec = objShell.Exec(ps)

' Close standard input before reading standard output.
objExec.StdIn.Close()

strStdOut = objExec.StdOut.ReadAll()
strStdErr = objExec.StdErr.ReadAll()

WScript.Echo strStdOut
WScript.Echo strStdErr
```

The code above uses a here-string (which is best suited for my script). However I have tried substituting this for a regular string but the result is the same. To do this, I changed the value of `strStringToPrint` as follows:

```vb
strStringToPrint = "$text = 'Please save the file to " & """" & "C:\test\" & """" & "'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the double quotes around the path twice:

- for VBScript
- for the commandline (the `Exec` call)

The former is done by doubling the double quotes. For the latter you need backslashes. You already have a backslash before the double quotes after the path (although probably unintentional), but not before the double quotes before the path.

Change this:

```vb
strStringToPrint = "$text = @'" & vbCrLf & "Please save the file to ""C:\test\""" & vbCrLf & "'@"
```

into this:

```vb
strStringToPrint = "$text = @'" & vbCrLf & "Please save the file to \""C:\test\""" & vbCrLf & "'@"
```

or this (if you want the trailing backslash in the path):

```vb
strStringToPrint = "$text = @'" & vbCrLf & "Please save the file to \""C:\test\\\""" & vbCrLf & "'@"
```

Comment: Joy - Two forms of escaping required! Thanks for the swift response. Your answer makes perfect sense and I have made the changes to my code. Much appreciated.